# Rust ndarray: How can i select rows of an array from indexes

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I have a two dimensional array  `Array2`, i'd like to be able of selecting rows

```rust
use ndarray::{Array2, Axis};

let subarray: Array2 = my_array.select(Axis(0), &[0,2,5]);
```

With that simple code i can select first, third and sixth row, but what about when the target indexes are built at run time, i mean i'd like to select from a `Vector` or any iterable that could be the input of a function, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the slice by simply borrowing on a Vector

```rust
let index = vec![0, 2, 4];
let subarray = my_array.select(Axis(0), &index);
```